# A question related to dot product of a null vector and a vector

Tags: vectors

My saw this equation in my book today that $0.a$ = $0$

where left $0$ and a are vectors and . is dot product

since $0.a = |0||a|cos\theta$

but null vector do not direction so, $cos\theta$ should be undefined.

Therefore $0.a$ must be undefined But answer is 0,How?

Also can anyone tell how to add a vector symbol, I am unable to find it

Comment: If you insist on using "vector symbols" (*not everyone does*) do so with `$\vec{a}$` to produce $\vec{a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*but null vector do not have direction so, $\cos\theta$ should be undefined*"

What you write is not the definition of dot products, but rather a *result* relating to dot products.  If you look at original base definitions, it should be clear that $\langle \vec{0}, v\rangle = 0$ for any inner product, in particular the euclidean dot product.

In fact, quite the opposite... the angle $\theta$ between two nonzero vectors $u,v$ according to a specific inner product is typically *defined* as $\arccos(\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{|u||v|})$ (*which is important since some contexts don't lead to intuitive meanings of angles otherwise*)